# angularjs - Passing scope parameter to component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

We can pass scope parameter to a directive

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
      info: '=' 
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html' 
  }; 
});
```

and use it as follows in a view:

```
<app-info info="app"></app-info>
```

A component can be used as a directive too:

```
<component-info></component-info>
```

But can we pass to it a scope parameter same as **info="app"** ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Component is just a special case of directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for a component you'll use `bindings` instead of scope. So your component definition will look somewhat like this:

```
app.component('componentInfo', { 
    bindings: { 
        info: '=' 
    },
    // ... and so on
});
```

Comment: How to pass this parameter to the controller?

Comment: This will already be available in your controller through 'this.info'.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add "this" :p